# How can I fit this table sideways on the page (rotated 90°)?

Tags: tables, rotating, sidewaystable

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twppages]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Results - Process Innovation}
\label{table1}
\begin{adjustbox}{angle=90} %ist neu
\begin{tabular}{||l | l | l||}
\hline
 Author & Year &  Result \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
 Calantone et al.\cite{calantone1988strategies} & 1998 & "Process innovation aims to reduce costs in production of the firm's products and services" \\
 \hline
 Papinniemi\cite{papinniemi1999creating} & 1999 & "The essence of process innovation is creation of value-added in business and manufacturing processes; "customer benefit" through process innovation." \\
 \hline
 Boer et al.\cite{boer2001innovation} & 2001 & "Emphasis is on problem solving, iterative problem-solving process which does not stop upon implementation, innovation process characteristics (uncertainty, complexity, diversity and interdependence)" \\
 \hline
 Francis et al.\cite{francis2005targeting} & 2005 & "Not all process innovations are within firms, process innovation is also possible at the level of the value stream or supply chain."\\
 \hline
 Crespi et al.\cite{crespi2008demand} & 2008 & "Within industries characterized by process innovation, strategies searching for flexibility and labour cost reduction emerge as key factors for productivity growth." \\
 \hline
 Romero et al.\cite{romero2012self} & 2012 & "Personal motivations among workforce seem to matter significantly for process innovation."\\
 \hline
 Ganter et al.\cite{ganter2013persistence} & 2013 & "The persistence of innovation describes the influence of past innovation activities on current and future innovation behavior and success. There is no true persistence for process innovation new to the market." \\
 \hline
 Liao et al.\cite{liao2015effects} & 2015 & "Innovation capabilities and innovation assets can help firms obtain a better performance in the earlier stage of innovation life cycle, but these drivers become relatively weaker in the mature stage."\\
 \hline
 Brem et al.\cite{brem2016innovation} & 2016 & "We define process innovation as the cumulative improvements to the entire(production)  process ,which is applied to create a product or service." \\
 \hline
  Brem et al.\cite{brem2016innovation} & 2016 & "We define process innovation as the cumulative improvements to the entire(production)  process ,which is applied to create a product or service." \\
  \hline
  Fabiae et al.\cite{fabiae2016implementation} & 2016 & "Process innovation can also include new ways of providing services, for example, a great number of services has been computerized." \\
 \hline
 Tuan et al.\cite{tuan2016effects} & 2016 & "Process innovation generates a positive impact on innovative-, production-, market- and finance performance." \\
 \hline
 Antunes et al.\cite{antunes2017relationship} & 2017 & "Process innovation is essential when organizations want to increase productivity and quality of their products, placing innovation processes entirely in line with the TQM objectives." \\
 \hline
 Jaumandreu et al.\cite{jaumandreu2017disentangling} & 2017 & "Mixture of different types of innovation (e.g. process and product innovation) is likely to mix their effects in unpredictable ways." \\
 \hline
 Jespersen et al.\cite{jespersen2018analysis} & 2018 & "Process innovation is defined as the introduction of new or improved methods into an organization’s production processes, service operations, or distribution models."  \\
 \hline
 Olivia et al.\cite{oliva2019innovation} & 2019 & "Process innovations are stimulated mainly to overcome the challenges in transforming laboratory production on an industrial scale production." \\
 \hline
 Guo et al.\cite{guo2019disentangling} & 2019 & "Process innovation is defined as new elements or processes introduced into an organization’s production or service operations." \\

 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Take a look as the `tabularx` package and use something like `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{llX}` instead. Also, remove the `adjustbox` and either use a `landscape` environment from the `pdflscape` package or a `sidewaystable` from the `rotating` package.

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, but `twppages` is not a valid option for the `article` class. You might want to correct that.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, will try it out. This is the template provided by my institute, I'm not sure if I can change that but will also look into it, thank you!

Comment: @leandriis it worked with \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{llX} and sidewaystable. Thank you very much!

Comment: Ok, it worked for the first table because the content was just as much to fit the page. However, my second table has too many items and exceeds the page.

Comment: Take a look at the xltabular package. This combines the features of tabularx and longtable to allow for X type columns and mid-table page breaks.